# How do I use my custom ItemReader - Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have implemented my own `ItemStreamReader` to make it `Synchronized`. However  I don't know how to use it in my `step`.

```
SynchronizedItemReader<T> implements ItemStreamReader<T>
```

That's my custom class. My XML configuration for the step is as follows

```
    <bean id="xmlItemReaderStep2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:report.xml" />
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="class" />
    <property name="unmarshaller">
        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
            <property name="classesToBeBound">
                <list>
                    <value>com.model.ClassNode</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

How do I use my `SynchronizedItemReader<T>` in the step?

Job config below

```
        <batch:step id="step2" next="step3">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="xmlItemReaderStep2" writer="testResultsWriter"
                processor="itemProcessor2" commit-interval="500" />
            <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="promotionListener" />
                <batch:listener ref="jobListener3" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
```

Comment: That's the configuration of your `StaxEventItemReader` which is an item reader , can you post your job configuration ?

Comment: @RafikBELDI : Done. I have updated my question with the job config

Answer (score 0):

Configure a bean named `itemStreamReader` in your xml configuration for your item reader and configure it this way in your step :

```
 <batch:step id="step2" next="step3">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="itemStreamReader" writer="testResultsWriter"
                processor="itemProcessor2" commit-interval="500" />
            <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="promotionListener" />
                <batch:listener ref="jobListener3" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
```

Comment: I modified my existing `bean` like this  <bean id="xmlItemReaderStep2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamReader">
  <property name="resource" value="classpath:customreport.xml" />
  <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="class" />
  <property name="unmarshaller">
   <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
     <list>
      <value>com.model.ClassNode</value>
     </list>
    </property>
   </bean>
  </property>
 </bean>

Comment: But it didn't work. Can you pls help me how to create the bean for the `org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamReader`